# pyodbc.Error:('HY000','[HY000][Microsoft][ODBCDriver18forSQL Server]SSPIProvider:NoKerberoscredentialsavailable(default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1051)

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, kerberos

I am trying to connect to SQL Database from a Linux machine using Windows Authentication Mode/Active Directory Mode and Python.

```py
drivers = [item for item in pyodbc.drivers()]
driver = drivers[-1]
print("driver:{}".format(driver))
server = '10.0.1.49'
database = 'QE2S_LASA01'
uid = ''
pwd = ''
Trusted_Connection ='yes'
TrustServerCertificate = 'yes'
Encrypt = 'yes'
Integrated_Security = 'SSPI'
con_string = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PWD={pwd};Trusted_Connection={Trusted_Connection};TrustServerCertificate={TrustServerCertificate};Encrypt={Encrypt};Integrated_Security={Integrated_Security};'
print(con_string)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
cursor=cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT @@VERSION as version")
while 1:
    row=cursor.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    print(row.version)
```

But instead I get this:

```
neouser@inpvm01:/DATA-HDD01/ingestion/neo_ingestion/NEO-LASA$ python3 python_table_import.py
driver:ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
DRIVER=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server;SERVER=10.0.1.49;DATABASE=QE2S_LASA01;UID=ITSERVICES\m53132;PWD=Dallastexas+6;Trusted_Connection=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;Encrypt=yes;Integrated_Security=SSPI;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_table_import.py", line 52, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSPI Provider: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1051) (851968) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Is there any way I can disable Kerberos in the script so that it logs in using UID and password mentioned in the script?

Answer (score 0):

The MS SQL use two modes Name/Password and Windows Authentication.

**If you use Windows Authentication**, the MS SQL expected login via SSO (based on login to the operation systems with relation to the Kerberos) and it is not possible to add name and password to the DB connection string.

**If you use Name/Password**, you have to mention these information (Name/Passwd) to the connection string.

Back to your example, it seems, that you use MS SQL with mode Windows Authentication and in this case SSO (with Kerberos) is needed and you cannot setup name and password in DB connection string.

If you need to remove SSO (relation to Kerberos), you have to change mode on side of MS SQL from Windows Authentication to the Name/Password and than you can specific Name/Password for login (small reminder, in this case name and password in DB Connection string will be different than login to the domain/Operation system).